# Summing Op-Amps vs Difference Op-Amps

Tags: operational-amplifier, differential-amplifier, summing, summer

How do you tell the difference between a summing amplifier (non-inverting) op-amp and a difference amplifier just by looking at its configuration?

Please note that in both of these cases, both the (+) and (-) terminals have inputs, thus leading to my confusion on how do you really know if it's summing or difference op-amp

Comment: Please add a schematic.

Answer (score 4):

> ... just by looking at its configuration?

So you are looking for a practical way.

The first thing I look for is the voltage divider coming towards the inverting input. See the R3-RF pair below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVB69e.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If I see this divider then I know something "positive" is going to happen i.e. this **MUST** be a non-inverting thing (non-invert**h**ing hehe). So, anything coming towards the non-inverting input will **NOT** appear with a minus sign at the output. For example, if there's a [passive summer/mixer](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/17/Par_summer_dac_1000.jpg/350px-Par_summer_dac_1000.jpg) it's going to be amplified without any sign change i.e. non-inverting summer/mixer.

---

If you see R3's bottom end is going to a non-zero voltage, say \$V_X\$, instead of the ground then it's going to appear as \$-V_X\$ in the output voltage equation. This could be an inverting summer, a differential amplifier (subtractor), etc. In any case, there's going to be a subtraction or sign inversion.

---

---

If you are looking for a more technical explanation, here it is:

Both of them can be thought of as "sub-genres" of the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYHGb5.png)</sup>

The equation for the output is

$$
V_{OUT}=\frac{1}{R_3}\Bigg((R_3+R_F)\Big(\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}V_1 +\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}V_2 \Big)-R_F \ V_3\Bigg)
$$

<sup>**NOTE:** If you add another resistor from another source (say, \$V_4\$) to the inverting input you can derive the inverting summer as well.</sup>

If you make \$V_1=0\$ the circuit turns into subtractor because \$V_{OUT}\$ becomes \$(a \ V_2 - b \ V_3)\$.

If you make \$V_3=0\$ the circuit turns into non-inverting summer because \$V_{OUT}\$ becomes \$(c \ V_1+d \ V_2)\$.

So,

- if you see the **non-inverting input go to the ground through a resistor**, that's a subtractor (diff-amp).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fg42BP.png)</sup>

Here, the output voltage is in \$(a \ V_2 - b \ V_3)\$ form.

- If you see the **inverting input go to the ground through a resistor**, that's a summer (non-inv).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1N1Qs.png)</sup>

Comment: ...and if you see a resistor connecting the output to the non-inverting input, either this is a comparator with hysteresis, a mistake, or someone is doing some really deep magic.

Comment: @Hearth ... or an oscillator (if this was not one of the things that you meant with "deep magic").

Comment: I forgot to mention oscillators. By "deep magic" I meant more "applying small amounts of positive feedback to maintain gain at very high frequencies", which is possible to do but dramatically reduces your phase margin.

Answer (score 2):

## Initial answer

Good question... the kind you don't see in textbooks... Here is an initial explanation.

### Comparison

The two configurations differ in how the two input voltages are applied to the circuit input:

- In the **summing configuration**, the two input voltages are applied *in parallel* through resistors to the single-ended (grounded) input of a non-inverting or inverting amplifier (the two resistors form a *passive resistor summer*). Two input voltages with the same polarity regarding the ground act in the same direction; that is why this configuration is summing. In the first case, it is a *non-inverting summer*; in the second case, it is an *inverting summer*.
- In the **subtracting configuration**, the two input voltages are applied *in series* to the differential (floating) input of a differential amplifier. Two input voltages with the same polarity regarding the ground act in opposite directions when traveling the input loop; that is why this configuration is subtracting.

Generally speaking, both configurations are summing. By changing the sign of one of the two quantities, they can become subtracting.

### How to tell them apart

- If the two input voltages are applied through resistors to the input of a single-ended amplifier, this is a *summing amplifier*.
- If the two input voltages are applied separately to the two single-ended inputs of a differential amplifier, this is a *subtracting amplifier*.

## CircuitLab experiments

The best way to understand the ideas behind these summing circuits is through step-by-step experiments; by them we can trace circuit evolution.

### Passive summers

The actual operation (addition/subtraction) in these op-amp circuits is performed by passive sub-circuits, and the amplifiers only amplify the result.

**Series summer:** The simplest way to sum two voltages is, according to KVL, to connect the input voltage sources in series. In this extremely simple configuration, the "summer" is actually the loop, a piece of wire... "nothing".

But there is a problem - the output voltage is "floating" and requires an amplifier with a differential input. Indeed, for now we still do not have this problem since we have initially connected a "floating" voltmeter (multimeter) in the place of the amplifier.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnqvxc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Parallel summer:** If we want to use a single-ended amplifier (with one referenced to ground input), we can sum the voltages through a 2-resistor circuit. It is a more sophisticated (2-input) version of the humble voltage divider. We can understand it by the help of the superposition principle. As you can see, this is a summer with weighted (x0.5) inputs because of the attenuation.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuIWls.png)</sup>

### Amplifier summers

We can compensate for the attenuation by connecting an amplifier with a fixed gain of 2 after the passive resistor summer. Since there are no special fixed-gain amplifiers in CircuitLab, we can use op-amps as such by setting the desired gain of 2 in their "parameters" window. Indeed, a gain-of-two op-amp looks rather strange, but it works.

**Non-inverting:** It can be non-inverting...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7HgAX.png)</sup>

**Inverting:** ... or inverting amplifier.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMf7Ya.png)</sup>

**Differential:** If we want to use a series summer, we have to convert its "floating" output to a single-ended one. For this purpose, we connect a differential amplifier with a gain of 1 (follower).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMbAwg.png)</sup>

### Op-amp summers

The amplifiers with a fixed gain above are implemented by op-amps with negative feedback.

**Non-inverting:** In the basic *op-amp non-inverting amplifier*, the summer output is connected to the non-inverting input, and the feedback network is connected to the inverting input.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f91EYl.png)</sup>

**Inverting:** In the basic *op-amp inverting amplifier*, both summer output and feedback network are connected to the inverting input.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPP3ec.png)</sup>

**Differential:** The classic 4-resistor op-amp differential amplifier combines the two (non-inverting and inverting) versions above with additional voltage divider (R1-R4) that equalizes the two input gains.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQVHIM.png)</sup>